# mui-Autocomplete dropdown goes up when the state changed

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I have a component which written with mui Autocomplete component. I have a expand-collapse ability in the component and ı keep the expanded collapsed values in one state.

When ı clicked to something that will change this state, my autocomplete re-renders as ı expect but dropdown list goes up. This is my main problem.

How can ı avoid this? Is there any prop or something to solve that ? I tried to manage with sholudComponent update but in that case, state changes but autocomplete not re-renders so it calses another problem.

Example gif belong here

[image]

I hold the expanded portfolios in expandedPortfolios state and when ı clicked arrow ıcon handle with handleExpand function and change the state so ı can manage which group will expanded or collapsed.

```
handleExpand = (portfolioName) => {

        var portfolio = (this.state.portfoliosAsGroup || []).find(p => p.name == portfolioName);

        if (portfolio) {

            let portfolioId = portfolio.id;

            let current = this.state.expandedPortfolios;
            console.log(current);
            let Ids = [];
            if (current.includes(portfolioId)) {
                console.log("filter");

                Ids = current.filter((i) => i !== portfolioId);
            } else {
                console.log("push");

                Ids.push(...current, portfolioId);
            }

            console.log(Ids);

            this.setState({ expandedPortfolios: Ids, expand: !this.state.expand });
        }
    }
```

```
renderGroup={(params) => (
                    <>
                        {console.log(params)}
                        <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", height: "20px", marginTop: '15px' }}>
                            {params.group != dropdownGroupTags.all && <IconButton size="small" onClick={() => this.handleExpand(params.group)}>
                                {(!(this.state.expandedPortfolios || []).includes(this.getPortfolioIdByName(params.group)) ?
                                    <ExpandLessIcon /> : <ExpandMoreIcon />)}
                            </IconButton>}
                            {params.group != dropdownGroupTags.all ? <WarehouseIcon /> : <AccountBalanceIcon />}
                            <Button onClick={() => params.group != "Unportfolio" && this.handleCompanyChange(this.createCompanyGroupChangeText(params.group), params.group)}>
                                <Typography variant="subtitle1" sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                                    {params.group}
                                </Typography>
                            </Button>
                            <div style={{
                                marginLeft: 'auto',
                                marginRight: '30px'
                            }}>
                                <Typography align="right" variant="subtitle1" sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                                    {params.group != dropdownGroupTags.all && `${(params.children || []).length} Unit`}
                                </Typography>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {/* <Typography variant="subtitle1" sx={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{(params.children || []).length} Unit</Typography> */}
                        <br />

                        {(this.state.expandedPortfolios || []).includes(this.getPortfolioIdByName(params.group)) ? params.children : []}
                    </>
                )}
```

Comment: Hi, could you share the code, recreating the problem from scratch is quite hard. Please check the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for some help and use correct [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) to increase getting a answer / help

Comment: ı edited the question, you cannot create live demo because there are other functions which are too long and private but you can think about some ideas with looking the code